# Data on FileSystem.documentDirectory not persisting over app store updates in ios

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store-connect, expo, testflight

I was working on a project that need some files to be downloaded into storage and later works offline . I am using Expo's `Filesystem` api to download the file and then saving the file in Expo `FileSystem.documentDirectory`

```
let directory = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'media/';
await FileSystem.downloadAsync(imageurl,
                        directory + 'filename.jpg'
                    )
                        .then(({ uri }) => {
                            console.log(uri,'uri of image')
                        });
```

The problem is when i was updating app in itunesconnect the data is not persisting.

Comment: The file name may have been changed. Use `FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(fileUri)`
 to search for that directory.

Comment: I'm also saving some text files using FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync.. it is persisting after updates..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are trying to recover that file with absolute path after the update. Use a relative path instead.

iOS will update UUID of directory each time you change your build (ex. different builds on TestFlight or different version on AppStore).
ref: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4261#issuecomment-494072115

What you need to do is to store the filename into some persistent storage and combine that with `FileSystem.documentDirectory` to recover that file later, because your file is saved and the relative path works fine but the absolute path has changed.

Here is an example of copying an image into the document directory and recover that file later.

```js
const to = FileSystem.documentDirectory + filename
await FileSystem.copyAsync({
  from: uri, // uri to the image file
  to
})
dispatch({ type: 'STORE_FILENAME', filename }) // Anything that persists. I use redux-persist 

// ...after you updated the app to a different build
const filename = props.filename // recovered from the previous build anyhow
const uri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + filename

// maybe you want to render that image
return <Image uri={uri} />
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This answer should also be in this issue: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4261. Too bad the issue is locked :(